# eclipse - Java Remote debugging does not hit the breakpoint

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty-8

I am using `Jetty 8` and trying to connect from Eclipse(Remote Debugging). I am using `Java 1.6`. I have the latest code in eclipse. The port is not blocked in firewall.
Jetty is running on port 8080. I opened the debug port on 5999 using the below command

```
 java -Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=5999,server=y,suspend=n -jar start.jar.
```

I opened the application in browser(https://[servername]:8080) and logged in to the application.
Later I connected in eclipse(Run-->Debug configurations and gave hostname and port(5999)), breakpoint is not hit when I browse through the application in browser. But I could able to see the Threads in the eclipse, only the code is not hit in eclipse

Comment: Which code ? Maybe the code you try to break on is simply not executed...

Comment: The Java code where I set the breakpoint need to get hit (as per my navigation in the browser). Tried in many situations and breakpoint is not hit in all the places.

Comment: The problem is solved. Created a new workspace in eclipse and did all the required configuration changes and did a build and copied the files to the server. It is working fine now.